# How do you account for lags when trying to find a correlation? [SciKit-Learn]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, correlation

I am currently trying to run a regression between two data sets. However the one lags behind the other, but I am not sure by how much or how strong the lag is.

Is there a way to find the optimal lag period between the two data sets? For example suppose the one data set shows a lag of about 12 months with respect to the other, but we are not sure this is the best period of correlation. In other words, a period of 14 months may show a stronger correlation.

How can we find this optimum lag period without running correlations for each time period independently?

PS: I am trying to do this all in python and with Scikit-learn

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cross correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) to find the lag that maximizes correlation between two functions. This is implemented in [`numpy.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html).

Here is an example that shows a clear peak in the cross correlation for two time shifted series:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)

n = 1000

x = np.random.randn(n + 100)
x1 = x[:-100]
x2 = x[100:]

c = np.correlate(x1, x2, mode='full')

plt.plot(np.arange(1-n, n), c)
plt.show()
```

[image]